# How to setup SSL on MariaDB hosted on AWS RDS with Embarcadero FireDAC

Tags: ssl, mariadb, c++builder, rds, firedac

I'am trying to connect to a MariaDB instance hosted on AWS RDS over SSL

Looking to the docs: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Connect_to_MySQL_Server_(FireDAC)

Seems I need to set those 4 params:

```
UseSSL=True
SSL_ca=ca-cert.pem
SSL_cert=client-cert.pem
SSL_key=client-key.pem
```

but Amazon only gives me a rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem

I don't know much about TLS/SSL. I need to generate those .pem files?
If yes, how?

I also tried to do like so:

```
            db_params->Add("DriverID=MySQL");
            db_params->Add("Server=my.rds.url.com");
            db_params->Add("Port=9999");
            db_params->Add("Database=my_database");
            db_params->Add("User_Name=my_user");
            db_params->Add("Password=my_password");
            db_params->Add("UseSSL=True");
            db_params->Add("SSL_ca=absolute\\path\\to\\rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem");
```

But it raises the exception

```
[FireDAC][Phys][MySQL] SSL connection error
```

Without user and password same thing...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Refer to this link:- https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-setup-mariadb-ssl-and-secure-connections-from-clients/  Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late at the party, but somebody else may need this.

**1. The server**

First, you'll have to make sure your user uses SSL / TLS encryption on authentication. In a MySQL console, run the following SQL statement:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'my_user';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for my_user@%                                                                        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, ... ON *.* TO `my_user`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*...' REQUIRE SSL |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If the result does not contain `REQUIRE SSL`, you need to enable SSL / TLS on your user:

```
ALTER USER 'my_user' REQUIRE SSL;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Run the `SHOW GRANTS` statement again to confirm that your user is now using SSL / TLS.

Of course, you'll have to run all this under admin / root, otherwise you won't be able to grant privileges.

**2. The certificate**

Then, you'll have to download the **proper certificate**, depending on where your RDS instance is located (ex. US East (Ohio) -> **us-east-2-bundle.pem**). Save that .pem in your path of choice. I saved mine in a relative path to my executable (ex. './Cert').

You can download certificates from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html.

**3. The code**

You're mostly correct, but for the sake of consistency, I'll setup everything on the connection from scratch. This is Pascal code, but you'll get the point.

```
DBConnection.LoginPrompt := False;
DBConnection.ConnectedStoredUsage := [auRunTime];
DBConnection.ConnectionName := 'my_db_connection';
DBConnection.ResourceOptions.AutoConnect := False;
DBConnection.Params.DriverID := 'MySQL';
DBConnection.Params.Database := 'my_database';
DBConnection.Params.UserName := 'my_user';
DBConnection.Params.Password := 'my_password';
DBConnection.Params.Add('Server=my.rds.url.com');
DBConnection.Params.Add('Port=9999');
DBConnection.Params.Add('LoginTimeout=15');
DBConnection.Params.Add('UseSSL=True');
DBConnection.Params.Add('SSL_capath=./Cert');
DBConnection.Params.Add('SSL_ca=./Cert/us-east-2-bundle.pem');
DBConnection.Open;
```